# Edit Search Box in SharePoint Online (Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, search-box

Basically, I am trying to edit the value of the search input on SharePoint Online. Instead of showing OOTB value "Search this site", I would like to show a custom text.

I have found multiple articles on how to achieve this on a SharePoint On Premises solution, but these solutions don't seem to be feasible using SharePoint Online, as they require editing property `ServerInitialRender` inside SearchArea.xml, as described [here](http://www.eliostruyf.com/branding-the-search-box-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

One OOTB method is to configure the search navigation in the site settings (Site Settings > Search Settings).  Create a search link, and the search input value becomes "Search ".  For example, these are my search links:

[image]

The first item is 'Everything', so it'll be the default value shown when the page is loaded (the rest are available via drop down).  Se my search input:

[image]

And drop down:

[image]

Not the most ideal solution, but it's something.

Answer (score 1):

Go into design manager under site settings>look and feel.

Go to 3. Upload Design Files. Map the displayed URL to a network drive.

Go into the mapped drive and open design templates>search and open the file called 'Control_SearchBox' (The HTML file, not the .JS) in notepad, or whatever you prefer for editing HTML.

On line 24 the value for the prompt is listed after an = sign. Replace the text there with your desired text, enclose with quotation marks.

Comment: I tried this solution but didn't work. I believe I also need to edit property ServerInitialRender inside SearchArea.xml, but I haven't found this file yet.